# MS-Access Beginner Replace Textbox Caption With Combo Box Selection on Button Press

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm a complete beginner, just trying out/looking into Databases as more of a hobby, and think Microsoft Access would be an easy way to start with the whole front-end forms and back-end combination.

I just have a form with a combo box [UserNameEntry] that you can select a value from a table 'Users' in a 'Alias' field and then just press a button [Command27], and another text box will have its text replaced by that string. This is more of a test/precursor before me wanting to set it to get the record matching the 'Alias' value selected in the combo box, then checking if another field in that same record matches a particular value.

I don't mind if any help is in the expression, macro or VBA builder, all is good to learn.

I tried the following expression in the On Click event of the button [Command27] (and many other alternatives) but haven't had much luck:

```
=[Command27].[Caption]="[Users]![Alias]=" & "[UserNameEntry]"
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems with this approach.

1. A caption is a constant, it can't be assigned an expression.
2. Make  a textbox that looks like the object you want.
3. You don't need an `OnClick` event. You can simply set the control source of the text box to an expression that points to the combobox value.

   `=DLookUp("[Alias]","Users","[Users].[UserName] = " & [UserNameEntry])`

Finally, if you want to use a click event you can. You would need to make a VBA procedure that contains the action. Then call that from the `OnClick` event.

```vba
Public Sub Command27_Click()
    Command27.Caption = "[Users]![Alias]=" & [UserNameEntry]
End Sub
```